# Controlling ABB robot using the new ABB driver

Tags: ros, abb

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working with a toolchain which is compatible with ROS industrial and uses ROS-I guidelines to send trajectories to ROS-I based robot controllers. Currently, I am using the `joint_path_command` topic to send the trajectories to the robot, but the new ABB driver does not seem to be subscribed to that topic.
I want to use the `RWS` interface to communicate with the Robot controller, as I am not sure I can access the EGM license.
Can I know how I may be able to communicate with my ABB robot using the `RWS` interface on the new ABB driver?
Eg. Is it possible to send the robot a trajectory over some topic or service using a `roscpp` based program?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/379897/controlling-abb-robot-using-the-new-abb-driver/) by [MohammadHashmi](https://answers.ros.org/users/75448/mohammadhashmi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2021-06-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I want to use the `RWS` interface to communicate with the Robot controller, as I am not sure I can access the EGM license.
> Can I know how I may be able to communicate with my ABB robot using the `RWS` interface on the new ABB driver?
> Eg. Is it possible to send the robot a trajectory over some topic or service using a `roscpp` based program?

No, unfortunately not.

`abb_robot_driver` uses EGM to control robot motion. RWS is only used for coordination (such as enabling drives, resetting the controller, starting RAPID programs, etc).

Without EGM on the controller, you can still use the RWS node (ie: `abb_rws_service_provider`), but not immediately to command any motion.

If you'd still want to use `abb_robot_driver`, you could:

1. generate a RAPID program (using some external library/node, not included with `abb_robot_driver`), upload that to the controller and then use `abb_rws_service_provider` to start that program. Or:
2. write a RAPID program which executes moves to a number of positions, upload that to the controller, and then use `abb_rws_service_provider` to update the data in that program (ie: update position variables based on your ROS trajectory)

Neither of these two options has been implemented (perhaps someone has done this, but I'm not aware of anyone making this available publicly), so this would require some work.

Perhaps a hybrid between `abb_driver` and `abb_robot_driver`, where the custom sockets used by `abb_driver` would be replaced by `abb_rws_service_provider` setting the variables would work. But again: that would require some custom development.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-06-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0